# Coinmarketcap giving #N/A and Loading.. errors when pulling prices

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, api, google-apps-script

Until about a week ago, my Google sheets code was pulling coinmarketcap prices with no issue. This then randomly stopped and has been showing an error; either #N/A or Loading..

When hovered over the error cells, it says "Error, Imported Content is Empty".

My research led my to understand that there is now the new coinmarketcap pro API replacing the old. Was curious whether this is what's causing a problem?

But I'm not yet certain whether that's it. Please help.

**Formula for pulling prices is (example):**
`=importxml("https://coinmarketcap.com/currencies/bitcoin/", "//*[@id=" & CHAR(34) & "quote_price" & CHAR(34) &"]/span[1]")`

**I then have a relevant script attached shown below.**

```
  function onOpen() {
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getRangeByName("TodayRng").setValue(new Date())
}

function getPriceStatic(coinName, currency) 
{
  try {

    var request_url = "https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/ticker/" + coinName + "?convert=" + currency
    /*var request_url = "https://pro-api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/ticker/" + coinName + "?convert=" + currency*/

    var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(request_url);

    var json = response.getContentText();

    var data = JSON.parse(json);

    var priceval = {"EUR" : data[0].price_eur, "USD" : data[0].price_usd, 
                    "BTC" : data[0].price_btc, "AUD" : data[0].price_aud, 
                    "BRL" : data[0].price_brl, "CAD" : data[0].price_cad, 
                    "CHF" : data[0].price_chf, "CNY" : data[0].price_cny, 
                    "RUB" : data[0].price_rub, "GBP" : data[0].price_gbp, 
                    "HKD" : data[0].price_hkd, "IDR" : data[0].price_idr, 
                    "INR" : data[0].price_inr, "JPY" : data[0].price_jpy, 
                    "KRW" : data[0].price_krw, "MXN" : data[0].price_mxn, 

                    "24h_volume_usd" : data[0]["24h_volume_usd"], 
                    "market_cap_usd" : data[0].market_cap_usd, 
                    "available_supply" : data[0].available_supply, 
                    "total_supply" : data[0].total_supply,
                    "max_supply" : data[0].max_supply,/*added by me*/
                    "percent_change_1h" : data[0].percent_change_1h, 
                    "percent_change_24h" : data[0].percent_change_24h, 
                    "percent_change_7d" : data[0].percent_change_7d, 
                    "last_updated" : data[0].last_updated }

    var price = parseFloat(priceval[currency])

    return price
  }
  catch(err) {
      getPriceStatic(coinName, currency)
  }
}

function getPriceUpdatable(coinName, currency, timestamp) 
{
  try {
    var request_url = "https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/ticker/" + coinName + "?convert=" + currency
    /*var request_url = "https://pro-api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/ticker/" + coinName + "?convert=" + currency*/

    var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(request_url);

    var json = response.getContentText();

    var data = JSON.parse(json);

    var priceval = {"EUR" : data[0].price_eur, "USD" : data[0].price_usd, 
                    "BTC" : data[0].price_btc, "AUD" : data[0].price_aud, 
                    "BRL" : data[0].price_brl, "CAD" : data[0].price_cad, 
                    "CHF" : data[0].price_chf, "CNY" : data[0].price_cny, 
                    "RUB" : data[0].price_rub, "GBP" : data[0].price_gbp, 
                    "HKD" : data[0].price_hkd, "IDR" : data[0].price_idr, 
                    "INR" : data[0].price_inr, "JPY" : data[0].price_jpy, 
                    "KRW" : data[0].price_krw, "MXN" : data[0].price_mxn, 

                    "24h_volume_usd" : data[0]["24h_volume_usd"], 
                    "market_cap_usd" : data[0].market_cap_usd, 
                    "available_supply" : data[0].available_supply, 
                    "total_supply" : data[0].total_supply,
                    "max_supply" : data[0].max_supply,/*added by me*/
                    "percent_change_1h" : data[0].percent_change_1h, 
                    "percent_change_24h" : data[0].percent_change_24h, 
                    "percent_change_7d" : data[0].percent_change_7d, 
                    "last_updated" : data[0].last_updated }

    var price = parseFloat(priceval[currency])

    return price
  }
  catch(err) {
      getPriceStatic(coinName, currency, timestamp)
  }
}

function test_onEdit() {
  onEdit({
    range : SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveCell(),
});
}

function onEdit(e)
{
  e.range = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveCell();

  if (e.range.getSheet().getName() != "Transactions") return;

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var ws = ss.getSheetByName("Transactions") 

  var currency = ss.getRangeByName("Currency").getValue();

  var row = e.range.getRow();

  var feeCurrColumn = ss.getRangeByName("FeeCurrencyColumn").getColumn();
  var acqCurrColumn = ss.getRangeByName("AcquiredCurrencyColumn").getColumn();

  var bookPriceEurCol = ss.getRangeByName("BookPriceEURCol").getColumn();
  var bookPriceBtcCol = ss.getRangeByName("BookPriceBTCCol").getColumn();
  var feeBookPriceEurCol = ss.getRangeByName("FeeBookPriceEURCol").getColumn();
  var feeBookPriceBtcCol = ss.getRangeByName("FeeBookPriceBTCCol").getColumn();

  var acqCurrNameCol = ss.getRangeByName("AcquiredCurrencyNameColumn").getColumn();
  var feeCurrNameCol = ss.getRangeByName("FeeCurrencyNameColumn").getColumn();

  var acqIsCryptoCol = ss.getRangeByName("AcquiredIsCryptoCol").getColumn();
  var feeIsCryptoCol = ss.getRangeByName("FeeIsCryptoCol").getColumn();

  var acqAmountCol = ss.getRangeByName("AcquiredAmountCol").getColumn();
  var feeAmountCol = ss.getRangeByName("FeeAmountCol").getColumn();

  var transDateColumn = ss.getRangeByName("TransactionDateColumn").getColumn();

  var a = e.range.getColumn();        

  if (e.range.getColumn() == feeAmountCol || e.range.getColumn() == acqAmountCol || e.range.getColumn() == feeCurrColumn || e.range.getColumn() == acqCurrColumn)
  {

    if (e.range.getColumn() == acqAmountCol || e.range.getColumn() == acqCurrColumn) {
      if (e.range.getValue().length == 0) {
        ws.getRange(row, bookPriceEurCol).setValue("");
        ws.getRange(row, bookPriceBtcCol).setValue("");
        ws.getRange(row, transDateColumn).setValue("");
      } else {
        updateBookPrice(ws , row, bookPriceEurCol, bookPriceBtcCol, currency, acqIsCryptoCol, acqCurrNameCol) 
        updateFeeBookPrice(ws , row, feeBookPriceEurCol, feeBookPriceBtcCol, currency, feeIsCryptoCol, feeCurrNameCol, feeAmountCol, acqAmountCol)
        ws.getRange(row, transDateColumn).setValue(new Date());
      }
    }

    if (e.range.getColumn() == feeAmountCol || e.range.getColumn() == feeCurrColumn ) {
      if (e.range.getValue().length == 0) {
        ws.getRange(row, feeBookPriceEurCol).setValue("");
        ws.getRange(row, feeBookPriceBtcCol).setValue("");
      } else {
        updateFeeBookPrice(ws , row, feeBookPriceEurCol, feeBookPriceBtcCol, currency, feeIsCryptoCol, feeCurrNameCol, feeAmountCol, acqAmountCol)
        ws.getRange(row, transDateColumn).setValue(new Date());
      }
    }    
  }
  Logger.log("exit")
}

function updateBookPrice(ss, row, bookPriceEurCol, bookPriceBtcCol, currency, acqIsCryptoCol, acqCurrNameCol) 
{
  if (ss.getRange(row, acqIsCryptoCol).getValue() == true) {
    var coinName = ss.getRange(row, acqCurrNameCol).getValue();
    var val = getPriceStatic(coinName, currency);
    ss.getRange(row, bookPriceEurCol).setValue(val);

    val = getPriceStatic(coinName, "BTC");
    ss.getRange(row, bookPriceBtcCol).setValue(val);

  } else {
    ss.getRange(row, bookPriceEurCol).setValue(0);
    ss.getRange(row, bookPriceBtcCol).setValue(0);
  }  
}

function updateFeeBookPrice(ss, row, feeBookPriceEurCol, feeBookPriceBtcCol, currency, feeIsCryptoCol, feeCurrNameCol, feeAmountCol, acqAmountCol)
{
  var acqAmount = ss.getRange(row, acqAmountCol).getValue();
  var feeAmount = ss.getRange(row, feeAmountCol).getValue();

  var finalEurVal = 0;

  if (ss.getRange(row, feeIsCryptoCol).getValue() == true) {
    var coinName = ss.getRange(row, feeCurrNameCol).getValue();

    finalEurVal = feeAmount * getPriceStatic(coinName, currency) / acqAmount;
    ss.getRange(row, feeBookPriceEurCol).setValue(finalEurVal);

  } else {
    finalEurVal = feeAmount/acqAmount;
    ss.getRange(row, feeBookPriceEurCol).setValue(finalEurVal);
  }  

  ss.getRange(row, feeBookPriceBtcCol).setValue(finalEurVal/getPriceStatic("bitcoin",currency));
}
```

Answer (score -1):

[Price](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TWPb3.png) For me this was working, but yesterday stopped and now is working again

```
=importxml("https://coinmarketcap.com/currencies/ethereum/", "//span[@class='cmc-details-panel-price__price']")
```

Comment: Actually I found problem can be in cmc api restriction. You need api key for working. I tried to ask but no response from them. I found solution here, but it is little bit complicated: https://medium.com/@paulgambill/how-to-import-json-data-into-google-spreadsheets-in-less-than-5-minutes-a3fede1a014a and import json from cryptocompare

Comment: or just =VALUE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(INDEX(IMPORTDATA("https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/price?fsym=BTC&tsyms=BTC,USD,EUR"),0,2), "USD:",""), """", ""))